# What stages of emergence of linguistic features are proposed among the world of scholars?

Tags: historical-linguistics, theoretical-linguistics, linguistic-universals, evolutionary-linguistics

In biology, there is a simple two stages distinction of the emergence of life:

- **Abiogenesis**, the emergence of a (very simple) life form from non-living matter.
- **Evolution**, the further emergence of features by random variations and selective pressure.

Are there proposed stages in linguistics (historical linguistics?) to subdivide the timeline according to particular key-events ?

**layman-assumption**:

- If so , how deep might the division complexity be?
- Would the division be very regular or perpaps far more subdivided at the beginning of the timeline?
- What might be the problems in in seperating the timeline in emergences bound to linguistics and those not a linguistic part anymore?

Comment: May I suggest you re-read, edit and clarify your question? To start with, the question in the title seems to be different from the question in the body of the text.

Comment: Do you mean linguistic phenomena? "Features" usually has a particular meaning in linguistics which doesn't make much sense in this context. And the answer will be that no one knows anything.